# Volume of a Pyramid Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, volume

Find the volume of a pyramid with triangular base bounded by vectors $(1,-1, 2)$ and $(1, 1, 1)$
and vertex located at $(3, 2, 5)$.

I am not sure how I would solve this. I know the volume of a pyramid is: $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}(\text{base} *\text{height})$, but with the given vectors, I am unsure how to solve this.

Hope someone can help me, would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: if you liked the answer @John wrote out, you are supposed to upvote his answer by clicking on the upward direction of the arrow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing since you're only given two vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ on the base that the third is found by connecting the heads.  In that case, the area of the base is

$$A_{base} = \frac{1}{2}|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}| = \frac{1}{2}|-3\hat{x} + \hat{y} + 2 \hat{z}| = \sqrt{14}/2.$$

The cross product also defines a normal to the plane containing $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$.  The equation of this plane is $-3x + y + 2z = 0$ since the origin is contained in the plane.

The distance to the plane, which is the height of the pyramid, is then

$$h = \frac{-3(3) + 1(2) + 2(5)}{\sqrt{14}} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}.$$

Then your volume is

$$V = \frac{1}{3}A_{base}h = \frac{1}{3} \frac{\sqrt{14}}{2} \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Hi @John , thanks for your prompt response. I'm a bit confused how you got the area of the base in the first part and how you ended with sqrt(14)/2? I understand what you did with the height of the pyramid and multiplying the vertex points with the corresponding constants of the plane. Can you please clarify the first part? Everything else looks great. Thanks again!

Comment: The magnitude of the cross product of two vectors is the area of the parallelogram with those two vectors as adjacent sides.  The area of the triangle is half this area.  The $\sqrt{14}$ comes from the square root of the sum of the squares of $-3, 1, $ and $2$.  It's the length of the vector cross product.

Comment: I know you used the cross product of the two vectors to get -3x+y+2z but I still don't see what you inputted from there to get sqrt 14? And why would you square root the sum of the squares? Sorry, but I still don't comprehend what you did there.

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, I stupidly forgot that you wrote it's the length of the vector cross product. So basically it's (-3)^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 and the sqrt of that. Thanks John!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** For two arbitrary vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, $\|v_1 \times v_2\| = \|v_1\| \|v_2\|\sin(\theta)$.  You should be able to find the area of the base using this fact.

**Hint 2:** $v_1 \times v_2 $ will give you a vector perpendicular to the base.

**Hint 3:** Let $u = \frac {v_1 \times v_2}{\|v_1 \times v_2\| }$, then $u \cdot v_3$ will give you the height of the pyramid, where $v_3$ is the vector to the vertex from the corner at the origin.

**Hint 4 (bonus):** The *vector triple product* $|v_3 \cdot (v_1 \times v_2)|$ gives you the volume of the parallelepiped defined by the three vectors.  How many pyramids will fit in the parallelepiped?